# Sorting amount without using query? Datatables Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have problem sorting amounts because i have other query that has computation. The sorting is based in the main query but I need to sort it with the total amount(with computation)

I tried to use sorting in datatables but its not working because sorting in datables is based on the main query.

```
$sql = "SELECT  mm.idno as idno, 
    TRIM(UPPER(CONCAT(mm.fname, ' ',mm.mname, ' ', mm.lname))) as fullname,  
    TRIM(UPPER(mm.branchname)) as branchname,  
    TRIM(UPPER(mm.address)) as outlet_address,
    SUM(dr.totalamt) as total_amount 
    FROM 8_membermain mm
    LEFT JOIN 8_directsalessummary dr 
    ON mm.idno = dr.idno    
    WHERE mm.status > 0 
    AND dr.status = 1
    AND dr.ispaid = 'Full Payment'
    AND dr.trandate BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'
    GROUP BY mm.idno ORDER BY total_amount DESC";

$query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);

foreach( $query->result_array() as $row ){  // preparing an array for table tbody
  $nestedData = array(); 
  $nestedData[] = $row["idno"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["fullname"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["branchname"];
  $nestedData[] = $row["outlet_address"];

    if(empty($minus_item_amount[$row["idno"]])){
        $minus_item = 0;
                }
    else{
        $minus_item = $minus_item_amount[$row["idno"]];
        }

    if(empty($return_amount[$row["idno"]])){
        $return = 0;
        }
    else{
        $return = $return_amount[$row["idno"]];
        }

    if(!empty($checkDRchecker[$row["idno"]])) {
        $minus_item = 0;
    } else{
    }

$total_amount = ($row["total_amount"] - $minus_item) - $return;

$nestedData[] = number_format($total_amount,2,".",","); //total amount
$data[] = $nestedData;

        }
```

As you see, the sorting of `$row["total_amount"]` is based in the main query. is there any possible way to sort the total amount?

Comment: Why can't you sort $data before returning it?

Comment: @DovRine How? Been searching for that

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the difficulty. I assume that $data is  global to this script and is ultimately the return value, so sort it after the for loop and before it gets returned.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: if that's not possible for some reason, you can create an intermediate variable in the loop, sort that one after the loop and then assign it to data.